# Mysql Order by query with keping track of alphabets

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
I have the following table with two columns

    ID              Name
    1               ABC             
    2               Acc           
    3               Bcc  
    4               Bdc
    5               Cdd
    6               Cvv
```

Is it possible to prepare a Mysql Query so that I can get a result from database 
in the following format

```
    ID              Name           Alphabet
    1               ABC             A
    2               Acc             A
    3               Bcc             B
    4               Bdc             B
    5               Cdd             C
    6               Cvv             D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, `Name`, UPPER(LEFT(Name,1)) AS `alphabet` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `Name`;
```

should do it.

If the capital letters are giving you trouble you can use:

```
SELECT id, `Name`, UPPER(LEFT(Name,1)) AS `alphabet` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY LOWER(`Name`);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, Name, substr(Name, 1, 1) as Alphabet
FROM yourTable 
ORDER BY Name asc
```

Comment: I think the syntax for `substr` is `SUBSTR(str, pos, len)`.

Comment: That is a valid syntax too. both works. I just verified it just to be sure.

Comment: The syntax `SUBSTR(str, pos)` means `SUBSTR(str, pos, LENGTH(str))` though.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT id, name, LEFT(name, 1) AS alphabet FROM your_table WHERE 1 ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Why `ORDER BY name, alphabet` and not just `ORDER BY name` ?